# Not able to run the Karate test cases on Jenkins Server. Working fine on locally

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, karate

I have created one java spring boot CRUD app and for which I wrote Karate integration test cases.

When I run the Karate test cases locally using the command "**mvn test**", it works fine. However, when I deploy the same application on the Jenkins server, the test cases fail with an error related to connection timeout.

**Error:**

19:47:02.094 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9000 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused), http call failed after 38 milliseconds for URL: http://localhost:9000/employees
19:47:02.095 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed:
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9000 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

I saw one question regarding this. May be there is a need to add plugin for chrome to fix it. I am new to Karate so not sure, how to do it.

**My config file:**

```
function fn() {

  var config = {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000'
  }
  karate.configure('proxy',  { uri: 'http://localhost:9000'});
  return config;
}
```

**Test case:**

```
Feature: Verify Persons

  Background:
    Given url baseUrl

  Scenario: Post Employee
    Given path '/employees'
    And request {"name": "Robin-201"}
    When method POST
    Then status 200
    And print response
    And print response.name
    And match response.name == "Robin-201"
```

I am using Karate-JUnit5 version 0.9.6

Any help would be really appreciated @Peter.

Comment: this is the type of question I personally think no one can help you - you have to figure it out yourself. take the help of some IT or networking folks if needed. maybe your jenkins server does not have network connectivity to your server. maybe you need to configure an HTTP proxy. all the best - and we certainly don't support old versions of karate

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas for your comment. I will let you know if I find anything